# Какой метод аутентификации нужно использовать?

Tags: angularjs, yii2, rest

У меня есть приложение на AngularJS. Нужно реализовать в нем чтение, запись и изменение некоторых данных в/из БД. Для этого, на сколько я понимаю, нужно создать REST-сервер. Моё приложение будет использовать методы сервера и тем самым реализует задачу.

Приложение будет размещено на дешевом хостинге, на котором из ЯП доступен только PHP. В качестве фреймворка я выбрал Yii2, т.к. работал с ним раньше. Получилось набросать минимальную реализацию REST-сервера, но дело дошло до аутентификации и здесь начались проблемы. В Yii2 существует три способа аутентификации:

> - HTTP Basic Auth: токен доступа отправляется как имя пользователя. Такой подход следует использовать только в том случае, когда токен
>     доступа может быть безопасно сохранен на стороне абонента API.
>     Например, если API используется программой, запущенной на сервере.
> - Параметр запроса: токен доступа отправляется как параметр запроса в URL-адресе API, т.е. примерно таким образом:
>     https://example.com/users?access-token=xxxxxxxx. Так как большинство
>     Web-серверов сохраняют параметры запроса в своих логах, такой подход
>     следует применять только при работе с JSONP-запросами, которые не
>     могут отправлять токены доступа в HTTP-заголовках.
> - OAuth 2: токен доступа выдается абоненту API сервером авторизации и отправляется API-серверу через HTTP Bearer Tokens, в соответствии с
>     протоколом OAuth2.

Я так и не понял, какой способ нужно выбрать мне? API будет использоваться только моим JS-приложением, которое будет находится на том же хостинге, что и REST-сервер.

Comment: я бы на вашем месте сделал авторизацию через соц сетей, используя oauth2 implicit flow

Comment: @Ali, авторизация через соц сети уже есть и она прекрасно работает. Но как она может мне помочь в случае с моим собственным API-сервером?

Comment: все что нужно в вашем апи сервере это определение userId, а userId можете вычислить от токена полученного от фронта. какой токен у вас будет рабочим можете решать сами. можно использовать токен соц сети прямо, но тогда приходиться в каждом запросе проверить правильность токента на стороне бекэнда. чтобы  избавиться от этого, можете при авторизации, первый раз фронт отправляет токен соц сети беку, бек проверить токен, если валидный то создает свой токен, связывает с юзер ид и передает фронту. с этого момента фронт себе сохраняет этот свой токен и с каждым запросом в заголовке дает бекэнду.

Comment: @Ali, я ни когда не писал REST-серверы, по этому прошу прощения за тупняки. Вопрос - как такой механизм защитит меня от того, что юзер может просто взять этот токен, подставить в свой запрос и накинуть себе виртуальной валюты?

Comment: в схеме авторизации рест только с токеном любой кто знает правильный токен может выдавать себя за владельца токена. Как защита можно сделать время жизни токена коротким. или надо будет дополнительная защита вроде связка токена с IP. 
Если нужна супер безопасность тогда наверно придется копать глубже.

Comment: @Ali, мне что-то уже кажется, что мне и вовсе не нужна аутентификация и авторизация в моем сервере. Если можно выполнить код, который будет добавлять виртуальную валюту на стороне сервера, то проблема разрешится сам собой. Сейчас попробую разобраться с этим моментом.