# Регистрация и авторизация REST API

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Всем привет. Хочу отделить полностью фронтэнд от бэкэнда. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно в данном случае реализовать сессии/систему доступа? Фронт пишу на Vue.js, бэк написан на php. Видел что-то про токены, мол, генерить на бэке токен и писать его в localStorage, но тогда ведь "злоумышленник" сможет подставить в localStorage своего браузера данный токен и делать любые действия от имени данного юзера. Вообщем, вопрос один: как правильно все сделать?)

Comment: Как злоумышленник узнает чужой токен?

Comment: @Alex78191 тут вопрос даже не в том, как он узнает, а какие последствия от этого могут быть и как от этого защититься. Узнать можно разными способами, от оставленного компьютера в публичном доступе до различных вирусняков, нагло заглядывающих в localStorage.

Comment: Можете сделать маленькое время жизни токена, если так боитесь.Сохранять его в session storage. Обновлять его при любом запросе. Дело в том, что на фронте данные скрыть нельзя, и это нормально так делать.Можете шифровать токен перед записью в локал сторедж. Алгоритм шифрования будет все равно открыт на джс, но все же это труднее достать чем просто в браузере.

Comment: @Alexxosipov это уже проблемы пользователя. Куки можно угнать и без REST API.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576596/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C